# Redirecting links to images that contains dot (.)

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, image-processing

This code is perfecty working only for the links that do not contain dot (.). For example: http://www.example.com/manufacturers/hyundai/hyundai-i40/hyundai-i40-4.jpg

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^manufacturers/([^/]+/[^/]+)/[^/.]+\.jpg$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

However, this is not working for the links that contain dot. 
http://www.example.com/manufacturers/hyundai/hyundai-i40-1.8/hyundai-i40-1.8-4.jpg

Any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_ACCEPT} text/html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^manufacturers/([^/]+/[^/]+)/.+?\.jpg$ /$1 [L,NC,R=302]
```